# Javascript onclick function working only after asyncchronous request.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form and in the form i am having a button for saving the data as well as resetting the form.And i am doing certain validation after clicking the save button, which include **synchronous ajax requests** too.I am using the following code

My form

```
  <form>
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     <button id="click">Click</button>
  </form>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#click").on('click',function(){
      disableButton('click');
      //Here i am having certain ajax requests with async:false
   });
});

function disableButton(element_id){
    $("#"+element_id).addClass('k-disabled');
    $("#"+element_id).attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

Here comes the problem.When i click my button the function is executed after the ajax requests.Since they are synchronous and **i cannot make them asynchronous** the function will be executed after the ajax request is completed.I want the function to execute first and show the changes in the dom and then the ajax request.So any help is much appreciated.

Comment: why don't you call it before making that ajax call.? I mean remove the inline handler and add it in the dedicated handler.

Comment: strange click event is triggered both from jquery and javascript?

Comment: It will not work because i had tried it.Since the ajax is asynchronous one the function will execute once the ajax request is completed and then only the changes will be visible in the dom. I gave both the handlers because the inline handler will be executed first.but it wont helped

Comment: The screen won't update while the synchronous requests are locking up the browser. You really should rework your code to be async instead of trying to fight it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
As Jason P stated in the comments, **you should find a way to make your calls asynchronous**. It's probably simpler than you think and it will spare you some headaches. Besides, it will also solve the problem you're struggling with right now.

**Original answer** (now integrated to the question as an edit by OP)
You could do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#click").on('click',function(){
      disableButton('click'); //call your function before the ajax requests
      // put your ajax requests here
   });
});

function disableButton(element_id){
    $("#"+element_id).addClass('k-disabled');
    $("#"+element_id).attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

And you can delete the `onclick` markup in HTML

Comment: It will not work because i had tried it.Since the ajax is asynchronous one the function will execute once the ajax request is completed and then only the changes will be visible in the dom..

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is defer the ajax request so that the call stack clears before ajax starts.

You can do this by using `setTimeout` with `0` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#click").on('click',function(){
      disableButton('click');

      // this will allow for the call stack to clear, then your ajax function will be called
      setTimeout(function(){
        //Here i am having certain ajax requests with async:false
      }, 0)

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is necessary for you to call the *disableButton(element_id)* function on *document.ready* or not. But if your use-case allows you to NOT call the function on *document.ready* then you could try something like this..

```
function disableButton(element_id) {

    $("#"+element_id).addClass('k-disabled');
    $("#"+element_id).attr('disabled','disabled');

    // make your synchronous AJAX call here..
}
```

to make your code a bit more readable/cleaner, you can wrap your ajax calls inside another function and call that function from the disableButton function. Just a thought.

Cheers.

Comment: Naming a function `disableButton` when it makes a network call is disinformation. That will not make the code more readable unless you rename it ^^. (Besides, it's not an answer to OP's problem)

Comment: I simply used the name disableButton for the function because it was part of the question. It was NOT my recommendation. Also, changing the order of execution of javascript may very well solve the problem. It has happened for me in the past. I am not sure why you say that it's not an answer to OP's problem.!